# Group and Display different column1 values under the same column2 values from Laravel Search Results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm working on an eCommerce system using Laravel 5.2 which has custom fields for categories.

The relationship and tables are as follows.

**Products Table**
Columns - ProductID, ProductName

I have two products (HP and Lenovo Laptops) whose data is shown on the *CustomFieldValues* Table.

The custom fields such as Brand, RAM, Processor, Storage Size are stored in the *CustomFields* Table.

The relationship between the Custom Fields and the Category is that we have different custom fields for each category.

For example, Cars might have Color and Transmission Custom Fields. 
I only selected the Laptops Category for this question. That is why CategoryID = 1

[image]

The custom values for each product are stored in the *CustomFieldValues* table

[image]

This is the controller

```
public function subcategories($CategoryID)
{
$subcategories = DB::table('customfields')
->leftJoin('customfieldvalues', 'customfields.CustomFieldID', '=', 'customfieldvalues.CustomFieldID')
->select('customfieldvalues.*', 'customfields.CustomFieldName')
    ->groupBy('ProductID', 'customfields.CustomFieldID')
    ->where('customfields.CategoryID', '=', $CategoryID)
    ->get();
  return view('categories.subcategories')
  ->with('subcategories', $subcategories);
}
```

This is my view

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
        @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
        <p>
          {{$subcategory->CustomFieldName}} - {{$subcategory->CustomFieldValue}}
        <p>
        @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

**The result is this**

Laptop Brands - HP
Processor - Core i3
RAM - 4GB
Storage Size - 500GB
Laptop Brands - Lenovo
Processor - Core i3
RAM - 8GB
Storage Size - 1 TB

Now, what i wanted to know is how to organize and display the data like the as

### Laptop Brands

HP
Lenovo

### RAM

4GB
8GB

### Processor

Core i5

### Storage Size

1TB
500GB

Can i get the required result using the existing result set but by looping through the array and rearranging or do i have to work on the Controller's query.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this to get result:

```
$data = DB::table('tbl_name')
                 ->select('CustomFieldName', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(CustomFieldValue) as fieldValue'))
                 ->groupBy('CustomFieldName')
                 ->get();
```

Result output is:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CustomFieldName] => Laptop Brands
                    [fieldValue] => HP,Lenovo
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CustomFieldName] => Processor
                    [fieldValue] => Core i5
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CustomFieldName] => RAM
                    [fieldValue] => 4GB,8GB
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CustomFieldName] => Storage Size
                    [fieldValue] => 1TB
                )
        )
)
```

So, now onwards you have to explore the "fieldValue" column to display output into your view.

Comment: Sorry but I updated the question before looking at your answer.Your answer was actually very useful, especially the query part. I was able to get the required results with one problem. The query returns 4 rows where the custom field values are separated by a comma. I was able to loop through them using foreach / explode. The problem is there is one fieldValue data which has core i3,core i3 (twice) while the others are HP,Lenovo...  How can i have distinct results in that column. Meaning only one core i3 for the specific record

Comment: No worries, I only selected Distinct results from the CustomFieldValue. I.e -
 I changed DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(CustomFieldValue) as fieldValue')   to   DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CustomFieldValue)) as fieldValue'))

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `groupBy` with `orderBy`. In the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

```
$results = DB::table('table_name')
                   ->orderBy('CustomFieldName', 'asc')
                   ->groupBy('CustomFieldName')
                   ->get();
```

In Eloquent,

```
$results = App\ModelName::orderBy('CustomFieldName', 'asc')
                   ->groupBy('CustomFieldName')
                   ->get();
```

In my case `groupBy` worked for me well to show similar types data. You can try this..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

This is the master table (CustomFields)

[image: This is the master table (Custom Fields)]

This is the Child table (CustomFieldValues)

[image: This is the Child table (Custom Fields Value)]

Now you have to specify Foreign key relationship with Both tables,

```
CustomFields.CustomFieldID = CustomFieldValues.CustomFieldID
```

Laravel provides Eloquent Relationship, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

write this function in App\CustomFields  Model

```
public function fieldValue()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\CustomFieldValues');
}
```

Write this code in Controller Function,

```
public function subcategories($CategoryID)
{
   $subcategories = App\CustomFields::with('fieldValue')->get();

   return view('categories.subcategories')->with('subcategories', $subcategories);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Render view,

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
        @foreach($subcategories->fieldValue as $subcategory)
        <p>
          {{$subcategory->CustomFieldName}} - {{$subcategory->CustomFieldValue}}
        <p>
        @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Now you may achieve your requirements.